# MSYS2: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Invalid arguments

Tags: bash, permissions, ulimit, mingw

I was a victim of a fork bomb of my own construction, and I couldn't figure out how to stop it short of logging off.  (Tools like ProcMon were too slow to get ahead of the newly started processes).

In order to keep a future one "under control", I want to reduce the maximum number of user processes in my MSYS2 (MinGW32) system from 256 down to 50.

I have these commands at the top of my **.bashrc**:

```
ulimit -S -c 0      # Don't want coredumps.
ulimit -S -u 50     # limit 50 processes
export FUNCNEST=44  # limit function recursion
```

and I get this terminal output:

```
++ ulimit -S -c 0
++ ulimit -S -u 50
bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
++ export FUNCNEST=44
++ FUNCNEST=44
```

Note the first **ulimit** command (for *core dump size*) works; the second for *max user processes* fails.

I am a member of the administrators group.  I hope that's sufficient authority, as my system does not have SU or SUDO commands, nor do I know how to logon on as (or switch to) root.  There is no **/etc/security/** directory for system wide limits.  MSYS2 in installed on Windows XP SP3.

```
+ id User
uid=197614(User) gid=197121(None) groups=11(Authenticated Users),197121(None),197616(HelpLibraryUpdaters),544(Administrators),545(Users)
```

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong, or how to limit the number of shells being spun off?

Alternatively, can you recommend a method of stopping an in-progress fork bomb?

---

Here is what **ulimit -a** displays:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2040
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Here is what **ulimit -Ha** displays:

```
+ ulimit -Ha
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 3200
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Here is what **ulimit -Sa** displays:

```
+ ulimit -Sa
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2040
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```